# Веб-сайт не парсится полностью

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Пытаюсь пропарсить страницу на флибусте, вот мой код

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = 'http://flibusta.site/booksearch?ask='


print ('enter book or author: ')
zapros = input()
url_request = url + zapros + '&chb=on'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')  #
print (soup.prettify())
```

Таким образом, выводится все, кроме того, что нужно

[image: Кода, обведенного красным просто нет]

Что с ним не так? Возможно ли, что он подгружается js'ом(на самом сайте в соурс коде нужная часть есть). Если так, то как его оттуда достать?

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь спарсить страницу на которой ничего нету. При этом на скрине выполнен поиск. 
Я думаю, так должно работать

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
search = '1984'
url = "http://flibusta.site/booksearch?ask="
url = url+search


print ('enter book or author: ')
zapros = input()
url_request = url + zapros + '&chb=on'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')  #
print (soup.prettify())`
```